# Writing a function in R to iteratively subset dataframe by time

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset

I'm working with a dataframe that contains cases across time, let's say 10/01/18-12/31/18. Currently, I've written a script that allows me to subset the data by date, and it requires manually inputting specific dates. Here's the script with a dummy dataset:

```
> mydata
                  date dummy
1  2018-10-01 21:41:00     A
2  2018-10-03 21:41:00     B
3  2018-10-12 21:41:00     C
4  2018-11-01 21:41:00     D
5  2018-11-02 21:41:00     E
6  2018-11-12 21:41:00     F
7  2018-11-15 21:41:00     G
8  2018-12-02 21:41:00     H
9  2018-12-07 21:41:00     I
10 2018-12-12 21:41:00     J

#put date into readable format
mydata$date <- as.POSIXct(mydata$date, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M") 

# TOCHANGE: Adjust time points accordingly.
t1 = mydata[mydata$date >= "2018-10-01" & mydata$date <= "2018-10-31",]  
t2 = mydata[mydata$date >= "2018-11-01" & mydata$date <= "2018-11-30",]  
t3 = mydata[mydata$date >= "2018-12-01" & mydata$date <= "2018-12-30",]
```

I feel this could be done more efficiently with a function, especially because I want to make subsets with different iterations of amount of time within the subset (e.g. every week, every other week, every month). I'm thinking perhaps a function that takes an input of the amount of time in days to keep for each subset, then loop in making subsets based on that amount of time for the whole dataframe? Or is it not possible put dates as an input, and it would make more sense to have # of subsets as the input?

How would you write a function that could do this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning a month variable then use `split` to build one list of data frames which provides better management than separate, similar month data frames.

```
mydata$date <- as.POSIXct(mydata$date, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M") 
mydata$month <- format(mydata$date,"%m")

month_df_list <- split(mydata, mydata$month)

# OCTOBER DATA FRAME
month_df_list$`10`

# NOVEMBER DATA FRAME
month_df_list$`11`

# DECEMBER DATA FRAME
month_df_list$`12`
```

Do note you lose no functionality of a data frame if stored in a list. And to rename:

```
month_df_list <- setNames(mydata, paste0("t", seq_along(month_df_list)))

# OCTOBER DATA FRAME
month_df_list$t1

# NOVEMBER DATA FRAME
month_df_list$t2

# DECEMBER DATA FRAME
month_df_list$t3
```

Answer (score 0):

data.table approach

```
library( data.table )
```

**sample data**

```
dt <- fread("id date dummy
1  2018-10-01T21:41:00     A
2  2018-10-03T21:41:00     B
3  2018-10-12T21:41:00     C
4  2018-11-01T21:41:00     D
5  2018-11-02T21:41:00     E
6  2018-11-12T21:41:00     F
7  2018-11-15T21:41:00     G
8  2018-12-02T21:41:00     H
9  2018-12-07T21:41:00     I
10 2018-12-12T21:41:00     J", header = TRUE)

#set dates as Date
dt[, date := as.Date( date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam" )]
```

**subsetting**

```
#subset by month == 10
dt[ month(date) == 10,]

#    id       date dummy
# 1:  1 2018-10-01     A
# 2:  2 2018-10-03     B
# 3:  3 2018-10-12     C

#list with subset for each month
lapply( unique(month(dt$date)), function(x) dt[ month(date) == x, ])

# [[1]]
#    id       date dummy
# 1:  1 2018-10-01     A
# 2:  2 2018-10-03     B
# 3:  3 2018-10-12     C
# 
# [[2]]
#    id       date dummy
# 1:  4 2018-11-01     D
# 2:  5 2018-11-02     E
# 3:  6 2018-11-12     F
# 4:  7 2018-11-15     G
# 
# [[3]]
#    id       date dummy
# 1:  8 2018-12-02     H
# 2:  9 2018-12-07     I
# 3: 10 2018-12-12     J
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I'm new to R and haven't heard of  data.table, that's a great fix. The input here is for month; would there be a way to input subsetting by week? or by every other week?

Comment: @c.lam you can use`isoweek` from the `data.table`-package, but when working with time/date, the functions from the `lubridate`-package are also woirth having a look at..